# What are auxiliary data structures?

Tags: data-structures

I know this might sound a bit too basic, but I wasn't able to find a good explanation for auxiliary data structures.

Comment: Auxiliary just means like providing support -- helping to solve a problem without directly solving it. So they're basically just data structures, same as usual. A person referring to them as "auxiliary" is just emphasizing the point that they're not directly solving the problem so much as providing support in implementing a solution, e.g.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Auxiliary data structure is a fancy way of saying helper data structure. Something you might use to solve a given problem and is terminated after the problem is solved.

For example, if I asked you to find the count of each element in an array. One way to do this is by using a hash table. You would store the elements in the table as keys and their occurrences as values. Then you could traverse the table and find the occurrences of each element. After you get the occurrences you wouldn't need the table, therefore, it's an auxiliary data structure. Taking up extra space for temporary period of time. I hope that helps.